# Offline image viewing problems in certain browsers

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, internet-explorer, src

I have recently started learning HTML and CSS as an absolute beginner ... I realise reading some of your posts just how ignorant I actually am!

This has ended up being a slightly different question than I initially intended to write, having been saved by Chrome ... but would now like to know if there is an explanation or if there was a problem with what I had done.

I have been in a real pickle with the lesson on images. No matter what I did to the src's url, they would not appear when opened. I even used the four different types of url src "code" I could find is all your and other posts (all images in the same folder as the .htm file by the way). These were my four codes:

```
<img src="file:///C:/Users/Anna/OneDrive/Project/Website/1st-step.jpg", alt="child standing on first of several steps", height="122", width="112" />
<br />
<img src="achieved.jpg", alt="person standing at the top of a mountain in front of sunrise, both arms raised", height="100", width="200" / >
<br />
<img src="C:\Users\Anna\OneDrive\Project\Website\a-tag.jpg" alt="screenshot from stackoverflow.com website with info on src url referencing", height="250", width="600" / >
<br />
<img src="./images/top.jpg", alt="arrow facing up", width="80", height="80", />
<!-- to see if using a different folder would change things -->
```

For "through-ness", before posting my question, I opened my .htm file again and noticed that whenever I double clicked on it, it was the Microsoft-Edge browser that opened despite my default browser being Chrome. I then decided I should try other applications before writing so I opened my .htm file in "Serris" (which has a "run" function), Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome. And FINALLY in Firefox all images but `src="C:\Users\Anna\OneDrive\Project\Website\a-tag.jpg"` showed and blissfully Chrome showed them all.

Could anyone explain why to me? Will I have the same problem when I finally learn how to upload the files to an FTP and then to a Web Hosting site?

I checked the properties of all my images and there were no restrictions or any security settings (which I read on a different post might have been interpreted by Edge and Explorer as a security threat or something) and am coding in HTML5 so unlike the solution found by someone in another post all I should write in "doctype", as far as I am aware, is `<!doctype html>` and `<html lang="en-gb">` (the other post I read had a much more detailed, and complicated, code and by so doing was able to see the images in explorer).

Sorry for such a long question but I am hoping you may be able to shed some light on this for me as I feel like I am missing something vital and fear I may be in trouble later on.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and for editing my question ... and sorry for being verbose :s

Answer (score 0):

It transpires that saving the document as `index.html` rather than `test.htm`solved the problem ... can you believe?!?

Hope this helps other novices like me :)